# Close Notepad++ when updating via Subversion?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, notepad++

Do I need to close my file editor when performing update commands via Tortoise SVN?  It seems to me that if I had the file open in Notepad++ and then I updated this same file, then I would overwrite the updated changes when I saved my file again since the editor is not saving the downloaded changes.  Am I correct in this thinking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you can control this in the **MISC.** tab of the preferences panel, under **File Status Auto-Detection**. You can tell Notepad++ to inform you if the file that's open has been changed.

If you check **Update silently**, the moment you tab back to Notepad++ it automatically reloads the updated file for you without asking. Here I have it unchecked; in that case it'll pop up a dialog asking me if I'd like to reload the changes or keep the old file (as dirty/unsaved).

[image]

Comment: So, once Notepad++ is brought into focus, it will update any changed files that are opened in the editor.  If I have unsaved changes, it will throw these out and replace it with the updated version, correct?  Is this why you do not have 'update silently' checked, to warn you?  If this was the case, how would you prevent from losing your changes?  Cancelling the changes in Notepad++, saving, then updating again via SVN again?  In other words, you could potentially lose your changes in Notepad++ by saving over them, right?

Comment: @Evil Elf: That's correct, so I prefer that Notepad++ warns me so I can decide. If I click No, I keep my changes but Notepad++ turns the file dirty, because the new saved version that it sees is the SVN-updated revision. When I save *my* changes to that file within Notepad++ then, I can always compare the changes between my work and the SVN-updated revision using diff. Saving the file as Notepad++ sees it, as long as it's in your working copy, won't cause the file to commit right away.

Comment: OK, We are on the same page.

It still may just be good practice to close Notepad++ before using TortoiseSVN to perform updates, huh?  Notepad++ saves the session on close anyways, so I would only be one click away from bringing everything back up the way I left it...

Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I correct in this thinking?

yes. Some editors can detect when a file has changed externally (I think Notepad++ has that setting too), but if you have made changes to the open file, there is no way the text editor can merge it with an update on the fly.